# ADD TO CART BUTTON DOESN'T APPEAR

Tags: product, addtocart

In both catalog and product page the "add to cart" button doesn't load. I get an infinite loader instead of the "add to cart" button. Does anyone know what this could be?? I have never encoutered this problem before.
[image]

Comment: Does the browser console has any errors? And the application and server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Look like issue in site's js file.
Please check any console error in browser or not.

Must be error is there.

Answer (score 0):

First check the console, is there an error show if not

Then check to inspect for "Add to cart" button tag
is placed or not?

I hope it would be helpful for you!